# why d3-3d.js function are not recognized?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d

i try to use D3-3d to represent 3d graph.

i first tried to use some example to understand how it works but when a try to copy paste this one
https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/ff4d3c8497d8436d4d8fdb9f0121d12d
or this one
https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/5e1254ae778e2854f0079350a0376528
i get the error : Uncaught TypeError: d3._3d().scale(...).origin(...).rotateX(...).rotateY(...).primitiveType is not a function

i changed the way D3 and 3d are imported and try on chrome and Firefox and it keep being here.

the only example I manage to launch is this one
https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/1c15016ae5b5f11508f92852057136b5

i don't know a lot about D3 and JavaScript so I am blocked.

The code is the same than in the examples and this is how a tried to import D3 and d3-3djs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-3d/build/d3-3d.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First 2 examples have a different d3-3d js file linked. May be that version is different to https://unpkg.com/d3-3d@0.1.2/build/d3-3d.min.js Try using the same javascript given in that block

Comment: thank for the answers but it did not work, have you other ideas ?

Comment: I copied the code from first block to https://jsfiddle.net/bandnak/qdz4es3o/1   It works perfectly fine